# Shadowing and Nested function

Tags: f#, shadowing

I want to understand how the mechanism of Shadowing and Nested function work.
For example:

```
let func y =
    let dup y = y + y
    let z = dup y
    let dup y =
        let dup z =
            let y = y * z
            y
        let z = y
        y
    dup z + z;;

val func : int -> int

> func 3;;
val it : int = 12
```

Can someone explain what happen here?

Comment: Wow O_o, what's that for a mad machine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to the following, where I've simply numbered instances of your names to help you visualize how shadowing is occurring.

```
let func y0 = 
  let dup0 y1 = y1 + y1
  let z0 = dup0 y0
  let dup1 y2 = 
    let dup2 z1 = 
      let y3 = y2 * z1 
      y3
    let z2 = y2 
    y2 
  dup1 z0 + z0
```

This can be further simplified, of course.  Since `dup2` and `z2` are never used, `dup1` is equivalent to `let dup1 y2 = y2`, and the whole function is equivalent to

```
let func y0 =
  let dup0 y1 = y1 + y1
  let z0 = dup0 y0
  dup1 z0 + z0
```

Which is equivalent to

```
let func y0 =
  let z0 = y0 + y0
  z0 + z0
```

by substitution.  This is the same as

```
let func y0 = 4 * y0
```

Does this help?

Comment: More than that, now I understand the necessity in the "rec" keyword.

Answer (score 14):

I think *@kvb* gives a very good explanation showing how the code evaluates. The code combines *nested functions* and *shadowing* in a pretty confusing way :-). I think it is useful to look at the two concepts separately.

**Shadowing** allows you to hide a value by a new value in the `let` declaration or a value binding in the `match` construct. It means that you'll no longer be able to access the original value. Here is a simpler example:

```
let foo num =
  let num = num + 20 // Line 2
  let num = num * 2  // Line 3
  num
```

Here, we declare a function that takes an argument named `num`. Let's say we call the function with 1 as the argument. On the second line, we declare a *new value* with the same name - initialized to *1 + 20* which is *21*. The third line again declares a *new value* and initializes it to *21 * 2* (because it sees the last declared *num* symbol, which has value *21*). On the line 4, we again access the last declared *num* symbol and we return *42*.

This is useful mainly whan you have some calculation that calculates some new value that should be use by all subsequent calculations. Shadowing allows you to hide the previous value, so there is no danger you will accidentaly use the original one.

**Nested functions** are quite useful when you need to do some local utility calculation that uses parameters of the outer function. For example:

```
let times x nums = 
  let timesUtil y = y * x
  for n in nums do
    printfn "%d" (timesUtil n)
```

Here we declare a utility nested function `timesUtil` that multiplies any number by the value `x` (which is the argument of the `times` function). Then we can use it later (on the last line) to do the operation without having to pass the `x` value as an argument again. So, the main interesting thing about nested functions is that they can access values declared by the outer function.

Comment: Hi Tomas, on the line 4, I think it's *42* not *41*.

Comment: Yep, thanks! Getting 42 as the result was my intention - I'm not sure how 41 managed to get there!