# How do I specify a type that shares a type definition with another type?

Tags: f#

How do I specify a type that shares a type definition with another type?

**The following code does not compile:**

```
[<Test>]
let ``move checker``() =
    { Position={ X=1; Y=1 } } |> moveBlack NorthEast 
                              |> should equal { Position={ X=2; Y=2 } }
```

This is because the record that I'm passing into the moveBlack function is mapped to RedChecker instead of BlackChecker.

> Type mismatch. Expecting a
>       RedChecker -> 'a     but given a
>       BlackChecker -> BlackChecker     The type 'RedChecker' does not match the type 'BlackChecker'

**More than likely, this error occurs because the last type to have this definition is RedChecker:**

```
type BlackChecker = { Position:Position }
type RedChecker =   { Position:Position }
```

**I thought I could specify the black checker by doing this:**

```
(BlackChecker:{ Position={ X=1; Y=1 } })
```

**And thus have:**

```
[<Test>]
let ``move checker``() =
    (BlackChecker:{ { Position={ X=1; Y=1 } }) |> moveBlack NorthEast 
                              |> should equal (BlackChecker:{ { Position={ X=2; Y=2 } })
```

However, the above code also doesn't compile.

**Here's the rest of my code:**

```
(* Types *)
type Color = | Red | Black

type North = NorthEast | NorthWest
type South = SouthEast | SouthWest

type Position =     { X:int; Y:int }
type BlackChecker = { Position:Position }
type RedChecker =   { Position:Position }

(* Functions *)
let moveBlack (direction:North) (checker:BlackChecker) =
    match direction with
    | NorthEast -> { checker with Position= { X=2; Y=2 } }
    | NorthWest -> { checker with Position= { X=1; Y=2 } }

(* Tests *)
[<Test>]
let ``move checker``() =
    { Position={ X=1; Y=1 } } |> moveBlack NorthEast 
                              |> should equal { Position={ X=2; Y=2 } }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# Records: Fields With Identical Names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231355/f-records-fields-with-identical-names)

Comment: I think the fact that you even look for something like this may point to a problem with your type definitions. Why have `BlackChecker` and `RedChecker` instead of `Checker` with an additional `Color` field? Other than the color, they're functionally identical, aren't they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The labels of the most recently declared type take precedence over those of the previously declared type.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/records-%5Bfsharp%5D) You should be able to do it like this:

```
({ BlackChecker.Position={ X=1; Y=1 } })
```