# f# duplicate definition

Tags: f#, shadowing

in F# powerpack math provider source code: I saw this (in `lapack_service_netlib.fs`)

```
member this.dgemm_((a:matrix),(b:matrix)) =  
 // allocate results
  let c = Matrix.zero (m) (n)
  // transpose
  let c = Matrix.transpose c
...
  // fixups
  let c = Matrix.transpose c
  // result tuple
  c
```

Why does this complile? does `c` get duplicate definition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is **shadowing**; at function/class/member scope, any local `let` bindings will be shadowed by subsequent `let` bindings to the same name.

See also [Shadowing and Nested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478079/f-shadowing-and-nested-function)