# F# confusing output

Tags: f#

I'm an F# beginner. I ran this code:

```
let printMsg() =
    let msg = "Important"
    printfn "%s" msg
    let innerMsgChange() =
        let msg = "Very Important"
        printfn "%s" msg
    printfn "%s" msg
    innerMsgChange()
    printfn "%s" msg

printMsg()
```

I expected that text output would be in this sequence:

> Important, Very Important, Important, Important

or this

> Important, Very Important, Very Important, Important

but I got this

> Important, Important, Very Important, Important

it seems that these functions don't comply with code execution order. Why is that, am I missing something?

Comment: Your function doesn't execute until you call it. You have two variables named `msg`--one hides the other.

Comment: You may find this question helpful to look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478079/f-shadowing-and-nested-function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all its important to point out that `innerMsgChange` does not do what its name promises: It creates a new variable called `msg` (which is entirely unrelated to the outer variable which is also called `msg`) with the value "Very Important" and then prints it. So in essence it prints the string "Very Important" and that's it.

So which order is the code executed in? Simple:

1. The variable `msg` is set to "Important"
2. That variable is printed.
3. The `innerMsgChange` function is defined, but not called (that isn't a step that's actually executed as such, so basically nothing happens on this line(s))
4. The variable `msg` is printed again
5. `innerMsgChange()` is called

   5.1. The inner variable `msg` is set to "Very Important". Let's refer to it as `innerMsg` to disamiguate.

   5.2. `innerMsg` is printed.
6. `msg` (which still has the value "Important" because it's entirely unrelated to `innerMsg`) is printed again.

Answer (score 1):

The output is as expected

1) Important -> printfn "%s" msg ( line 3)

then you define the function, not call it.

2) Important -> printfn "%s" msg ( line 7)

Now, you call it.

3) Very Important -> printfn "%s" msg (line 6 inside function innerMsgChange)

4) Important -> printfn "%s" msg ( line 9)