# Binding new values in a function to names (identifiers) that are already named?

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

In the book "Expert F# 3.0", there is a text-parsing example to 'lex' and 'parse' polynomial expressions. I was trying to understand it a bit (there was no explanation for the code written) and I came across functions such as this:

```
let parseIndex src =
    match tryToken src with
        | Some(Hat,src) ->
            match tryToken src with
            | Some(Int num,src) -> (num,src)
            | _ -> failwith "expected an int after ^"
        | _ -> (1,src)
```

which uses the function

```
let tryToken (src:TokenStream) = 
    match src with 
    | head::rest -> Some(head, rest)
    | _ -> None
```

the function `parseIndex` uses the parameter `src` and as the code progresses by using `tryToken` multiple times,every time, the returned `src` is somehow something else but the function still uses that name!

my question is: what is `parseIndex` really doing here with `src`? because on the second pattern-matching, it uses `src` as if it was a deffirent value given by `tryToken`, but looking at tryToken, I see that it should give the same result on every use with pattern-matching.

the `Hat` and `Int` you see are union cases of `Token`, as `type TokenStream = Token list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later bindings shadow, or hide, earlier bindings. You can bind `x` as many times as you like:

```
let x = 1
let x = 2
let x = 3
...
```

The remainder of the scope will only see the last one.

Comment: so when you use x, you get the last bound value to x? but src is not being rebound!

Comment: @ZaidAjaj : It is in the match pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I stated that incorrectly (fixed). Shadowing is *per scope*. It's not rebinding prior values but hiding them. Once you leave the inner scope, the outer `src` is visible again.

Comment: @ZaidAjaj: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2478079/162396) has some useful examples.

Comment: so by the second pattern-matching, are we using src given from Some(Hat,src) or from the parameter of the function?

Comment: You are using the last definition visible from that scope (so, from the pattern match).

Comment: @Daniel thanks man, the examples were indeed helpful, i changed the names to src1 and src2 and now it's a bit more readable!

Comment: @ZaidAjaj In cases like this shadowing is sometimes used to intentionally hide previous values which should only be used in the outer scope.  In this example, hiding the origional `src` binding prevents it from being used in the inner scope.

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel says, this is called shadowing.

It's actually really useful in many situations; imagine this C# function:

```
public void DoStuff(string s)
{
    var trimmed = s.Trim();

    // For the rest of this function, we should use trimmed, but s is
    // sadly still in scope :( 
}
```

Shadowing can fix this issue by hiding the original variable:

```
let DoStuff s =
    let s = s.Trim()
    // Only one 's' is in scope here, and it's trimmed
```